# Please leave some space on the active page for new posts instead of filling it with tag edits

Tags: discussion, retagging

The [active home page](https://writing.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) has 48 slots to show posts in, according to my count. The last time I checked, 5 of those slots show new answers being posted and 2 show new questions being posted. *Everything else* is an edit, mainly due to a couple of users retagging old questions en masse. (Some of the other edits are on new posts, but you can't tell the age of the post on this screen.)

While I know how to [find a list of all new posts](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=*), I should not have to do this. There are also people who rely entirely on the home page out there, so this is also preventing them from seeing new content.

It's unfortunate that the system works this way, but it is what it is. I'm just asking everyone to please try to limit your retaggings (and other minor edits done on old posts) to a handful of threads each day so that new content can be easily seen. While properly tagged posts are important, people come here for the for the content, and new content is hard to see with so much noise on the home page.

Thank you.

---

I didn't see any discussion of this here on Writing (meta), although this has been heavily discussed elsewhere on the network:

- Meta Stack Overflow: [How should we handle the (ongoing) mass editing on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373201/6083675)
- Science Fiction and Fantasy: [Massive Retagging/Editing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1744/82909)
- Travel: [Poll on mass editing / 'flooding' / re-tagging impacts (of older posts)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4363)

Comment: Please, yes, *please!*

Answer (score 5):

I realize most of it is my doing.  I don't normally do massive numbers of retags but I was revamping the age-genre tags (**after discussing it on Meta**) and it was easier and more productive to do them together (though I spread it out over 2 days).  I added a few more but have stopped.  Mostly I only retag old posts if they've already come up in the active list for something someone else did.

**Retagging is important though.**

I would rather have a temporary flood in order to support retagging projects.  I realize there are disadvantages, but I don't know another way to accomplish this.  It's a necessary evil.